# Updating where another table equals some value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

How do I do the following in MySQL:

```
UPDATE PartTbl SET aFlag = 0 
WHERE PartId = (SELECT PartId FROM CategoryTbl WHERE cat = 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE PartTbl SET aFlag = 0 
WHERE PartId IN (SELECT PartId FROM CategoryTbl WHERE cat = 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `"IN"` instead of `"="` operator in the WHERE clause or use this code:

```
UPDATE A
    SET aFlag = 0
    From    PartTbl     As  A
    Inner   Join
        CategoryTbl As  B
    On  A.PartId    =   B.PartId
    WHERE B.cat = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE PartTbl pt SET aFlag = 0 
WHERE exists (
   SELECT PartId FROM CategoryTbl ct 
    WHERE cat = 100 and pt.partId = ct.partId)
```

Comment: `EXISTS` has a different meaning than `IN` and only checks, whether a result was returned at all. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: @feeela - this query is valid. Notice the correlation in the subquery within the `EXISTS`. Think of it as updating each record in `PartTbl` for which there exists a row in `CategoryTbl` that has a matching `partId` and a `cat` of 100.

Comment: @feeela Actually it should work. Try it. IN tends to break the query when you have null values.

Comment: Well, OK. I didn't knew about `EXISTS` until today, just quickly scanned the manual.

Comment: @feeela When performance is no issue it's probably a question of would you think is more readable. :)